# Mixtures and Replacement

Tags: ratio

How to approach this question?

Let's say we have 40 l of water.
Operation 1) 4 l water take out and 4 l juice replaced
Operation-2)5 l water taken out and 5 l juice replaced
and so on
what would be the water's concentration at the end of nth operation

Comment: Operation (2) cannot be carried out after operation (1) has been taken.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you have $$w+j=40$$ liters of well-mixed water ($w$) and juice ($j$) and replace $k$ liters of it by $k$ liters of juice then you end up with  $$w'+j'=40$$

where $$w'=(1-\frac{k}{40})w$$ and $$j'=(1-\frac{k}{40})j+k$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question  seems confused on two counts:

(a) After operation 1, you can only take out a **mixture** and replace by juice.

(b) Operation 1 mentions 4L exchange, operation 2 mentions 5L **and so on.** I   am answering on  the assumption that in each of **n** operations, you intended an exchange of 4L from a cask of 40L.

1. After operation 1, fraction of water left in cask  = 36/40 = 0.9.
2. Any subsequent operation will lower the amount of water to 0.9 of the water that was **left**, hence after operation 2, fraction of water left in cask  = $0.9^2$.
3. Thus after **n** operations, fraction of water left in cask  = $0.9^n$.
4. Generalising, if you leave behind water = fraction *f* of that remaining each time, the concentration (= fraction) of water after n operations will be *$f^n$*
5. Finally, if you **really** meant different fractions left behind in each operation, concentration will simply be *$f_1\times f_2\times f_3\times....\times f_n$*